# Fontifying certain commands using AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

One thing I've noticed when using AUCTeX recently is that sometimes some commands are not fontified by default such as `\maketitle` and the fontifying for something like `\setlength{\droptitle}{-5em}` is incorrect as it fontifies `\droptitle` as if it were an argument. I was wondering if there's a way to handle the first so that all statements that begin with `\` are fontified as a LaTeX command and possibly change the way it handles `\setlength`, it's not really a big deal for me it's just that the way it gets handled in Emacs sometimes confuses me when they show up as white text compared to the rest of the commands.

Essentially if it has a `\` in front of it I would like the way that Emacs highlights it by default (which it usually does and treats all things that start with `\` as commands and highlights it appropriately).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the cursor on a command you'd like to change the highlighting and type M-x customize-face . Emacs will come up with the variables and you can customize them to your hearts content.

But beware. You can make a real mess.

Comment: It changes it and makes the changes in my .emacs file but for some reason for the setlength command it still shows \droptitle in argument style font. Not a big deal to me although I tried to remove setlength from the keywords list in auctex and readd it with a new format but that didn't work for me either.