# AUCTeX: How can I add syntax highlighting for custom cite commands?

Tags: citing, editors, auctex

I'm new to Emacs and AUCTeX and I want to have consistent syntax highlighting.

Besides the "normal" `\cite` command, I'm also using commands like `\citeauthor` or `\Citeauthor`or self defined commands like `\cians{...}` which have bibtex keys as arguments and are used to cite literature.

- How can I change syntax coloring in AUCTeX so that those commands and their arguments have the same colors as the `\cite` command?

*I'm sorry, I'm not very experienced with Emacs, so for me those customizations are very difficult, I tried and found the `Font Latex User Keyword Classes`, but I do not know how to apply them (if this should be the right solution).*

Comment: This question might be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42086/3731.

Comment: @Ricardo: thanks, this was indeed helpful. however I'd also like to know how to add more commands to the list of those who are treated as citations or references

Comment: These two questions might be useful, as far as fontification goes: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42086/3731 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86119/3731.

Comment: Check if this question helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31966/3731 If not, consider opening a new question, in the spirit of one post per question, so that other users may find it more easily.

Comment: @Ricardo: I turned your answer post to a comment. Links to other answers do not qualify as new answers on this site, but should be posted as comments. If they actually answer the question it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, thanks for that. That's why I flagged it in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

As described in [this answer to *AUCTeX – new commands recognized as such*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86119/5701) you can [fontify macros of choice](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Fontification-of-macros.html) by adding them to the variable `font-latex-match-reference-keywords` which is meant to list

> Keywords for macros defining or related to references, like ‘\ref’.

Thus, to fontify the macros you mention add the following to your .emacs:

```lisp
(setq font-latex-match-reference-keywords
  '(
    ("citeauthor" "[{")
    ("Citeauthor" "[{")
    ("cians" "[{")))
```