# How to set syntax highlighting for \citep as same as \cite in AUCTeX?

Tags: macros, auctex

It would be better to have uniform syntax highlighting for both `\citep` and `\cite` as it appears quite a lot in my manuscript.

I tried to implement what was suggested in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88728/77071) like so

```
(setq font-latex-match-reference-keywords
  '(
    ("citeauthor" "[{")
    ("citep" "[{")))
```

The above lines were added to my `~\.emacs\init.el` file. Though it works for `\citeauthor`, it doesn't effect `\citep` which still appears sedated.

Is there a solution to make this work?

Comment: Are you using `natbib` or `biblatex`?  And which AUCTeX version do you have installed?

Comment: @ArashEsbati, the AUCTeX version is 11.88; I'm running `pdflatex` without `natbib` package. I'm working with `elsarticle` class and I doubt it uses `biblatex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 solutions for your question.

### Prerequisite

Update AUCTeX to latest version 11.90.  I suggest you do it via ELPA as described in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Installation).  If you do so, please also read [Quick Start](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Quick-Start).  And definitely put this in your init file:

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

### Quick fix solution

`elsarticle.cls` internally loads `natbib`, `graphicx` and some other packages.  AUCTeX does not parse the .cls file to be aware of this.  You can give AUCTeX a hint by loading these packages again in the preamble of your .tex file.  With `TeX-parse-self` set to `t`, AUCTeX loads its support files (jargon: style files) for these packages and your file will look like this:

[image]

Also note that now you get auto-completion support for macros provided by `natbib` when you hit <kbd>C-c C-m citep RET</kbd>.  Things get even better if you use RefTeX.

### Long-term solution

This includes writing an AUCTeX support file `elsarticle.el`.  For what you're asking, the following lines will be sufficient:

```lisp
;;; elsarticle.el --- AUCTeX style for `elsarticle.cls'

(TeX-add-style-hook
 "elsarticle"
 (lambda ()
   (TeX-run-style-hooks "natbib" "graphicx" "geometry")))
```

Customize the variable `TeX-style-private` to a directory of your choice, e.g.

```lisp
(setq TeX-style-private (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/auctex-styles"))
```

Save `elsarticle.el` in that directory, restart Emacs and load your .tex file.  This should then work without reloading `natbib` and `graphicx` in your preamble.

Comment: Updating AUCTeX through ELPA solved the problem (`(setq TeX-parse-self t)` was in my `init.el` all the time). So guess that this was some sort of bug in the 11.88 version. Thank you very much.

Comment: For me it works by putting the `(TeX-add-style-hook ...)`  for the custom dtx file in my .emacs.

Comment: @ChristianHerenz - This is exactly what I don't recommend: Polluting a `.emacs` with code where AUCTeX provides a clear interface for.

Comment: For me it appears much easier to have just one file that I sync between all my machines that contains ALL my settings and customisations.  Note that I forgot that the construct needs to be put in the `(with-eval-after-load "tex" ... )` construct.